# Auomated crash recovery?

Tags: backup, fatal-error, troubleshooting, automation

Is there, or do you know of any in development, a solution that will provide **push-button recovery when a plugin update causes a crash???**

Many systems now provide push-button rollback to a backup *if* the system is still stable; but I don't know of any that allow this if a plugin causes a site crash.

I know how to recover a site manually (using SFTP, phpMyAdmin, or what have you). But I feel like there should be a way to do this automated.

Thanks!

Comment: Something is being worked on for this in core: https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/44458 https://twitter.com/schlessera/status/1015724980796084225

Answer (score 0):

I believe you're looking for [VaultPress](https://vaultpress.com/) from [Automattic](https://automattic.com/) - here's their [guide to one-click restore](https://help.vaultpress.com/one-click-restore/) (con: it's not a free plugin).